# image binding to the drodown values in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

In my xaml form i have a dropdown button the dropdown values will bind from database and my requirement is i want to add one image for each dropdown value in the dropdown box, how can get this.....

```
<ctrl:DropDownButton Grid.Column="1"
                                     Height="25"
                                     Text="Add Question"
                                     Width="125"
                                     Margin="5,0,10,0">
                    <ctrl:DropDownButton.DropDownContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource QuestionTypes}}">
                            <ContextMenu.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Background="WhiteSmoke"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ContextMenu.ItemsPanel>
                            <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.AddQuestionCommand, 
                                                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
                                    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}" />
                                </Style>
                            </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Margin="-20,0,-50,0">
                                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource EnumDescriptionConverter}}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </ctrl:DropDownButton.DropDownContextMenu>
                </ctrl:DropDownButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

*I wrote this outside of VisualStudio so please check the syntax

you should add an Image element to your DataTempalte and using a converter for the enum value resolve the path to the image you would like to present.

```
        <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <Grid Margin="-20,0,-50,0">
                      <Grid>
                          <Grid.ColumnDefenitions>
                               <ColumnDefenition />
                               <ColumnDefenition />
                           </Grid.ColumnDefenitions>
                           <Image Source="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource EnumImageConverter}}" />
                           <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=., Converter={StaticResource EnumDescriptionConverter}}"/>
                   </Grid>
               </DataTemplate>
       </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: using a converter . 
post your EnumDescriptionConverter